# org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface + google cloud sql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to hold a member of an abstract class in a concrete class using hibernate.

My classes are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente2")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn
(
 name="tipo_collocazione",
 discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
public abstract class Utente2  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private Long idUtente;
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "cognome")
    private String cognome;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Utente2() {}

    public Long getIdUtente() {
        return idUtente;
    }

    public void setIdUtente(Long idUtente) {
        this.idUtente = idUtente;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public abstract String getCollocazione();

}

    @Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INTERNO")
public class UtenteInterno extends Utente2 {

    @Column(name = "collocazione")
    private String collocazione;

    public UtenteInterno(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCollocazione() {
        return "Collocazione interna: " + getCollocazione();
    }

    public void setCollocazione(String collocazione) {
        this.collocazione = collocazione;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ESTERNO")
public class UtenteEsterno extends Utente2 {

@Column(name = "collocazione")
private String collocazione;

public UtenteEsterno(){
    super();
}

@Override
public String getCollocazione() {
    return "Collocazione esterna - indirizzo: " + getCollocazione();
}

public void setCollocazione(String collocazione) {
    this.collocazione = collocazione;
}

}
```

and the final problem is

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : googleTest2.HelloGoogle3.entities.Utente2
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:114)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:136)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:737)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4761)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1427)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1415)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1619)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:202)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.findByNome(Unknown Source)
at googleTest2.HelloGoogle3.controller.HomeController.testDBjpa1_repo(HomeController.java:245)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:502)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

In the db I have table utente2 with 2 records. One with discriminator column "INTERNO" and one with disscrinator column "ESTERNO".
This configuration work well if, for example, I run the app with tomcat, but now I want to run it with google app engine...
When, in the controller, I make the request like

```
Utente2 utente = utenteRepo.findByNome("NameUtente");
```

I have the previous error...

Does it change something with this hibernate configuration when I run the app on google app engine + google cloy sql (mysql db) ?

thanks

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? When you run the application under Tomcat, are you connecting to the same database? Can you run a query to select the row you are retrieving and include the raw output in your question? It's more likely to be a Hibernate issue than a database-specific issue.

Comment: I'm using hibernate 4.3.10.Final or 4.2.0.Final because I'm tryng to resolve other problems that seem related to compatibility of Hiberanate and jpa. I'm running on a google server app engine...The problem was that I missed to map class and subclasses in my persistence.xml....Now I managed my pom.xml to have the same version of hibernate libraries, and force to use jpa 2.0 but I have this error 

'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;'

Thanks

Comment: If your initial question is resolved, please post the solution as an answer to this post so that other readers can learn from it if they run into the same problem. If you have a new issue, I suggest posting a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I missed to map class and subclasses in my persistence.xml.